# Ubuntu 12.04.2 Dual boot UEFI Windows 8 Preinstalled CX21903W Ultrabook

Tags: dual-boot, uefi

Hi i have a problem trying to install ubuntu. The machine is a CX Ultrabook model CX.21903W Intel I5 with 500GB hard disk, 8 GB ram and 32 GB SSD.

From [Installing Ubuntu Alongside a Pre-Installed Windows with UEFI](https://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-on-a-pre-installed-windows-8-64-bit-system-uefi-supported), and according to the steps guide:

1. We create a partition from Win8 (70 GB) using the win8 program.
2. Confirm-SecureBootUEFI=True.
3. From Win8, <kbd>shift</kbd> + **Restart** and from special menu we selected the UEFI Firmware Setting.
4. From BIOS Option:

   - Option 1) Disable Secure Boot.
   - Option 2) Disable UEFI (Not Available)
   - from Option 1: Three  ways is available.
   - With Secure Boot enable -> We can't  even boot ubuntu. A red windows saying Soft unproper signed.

   With Secure Boot disable -> and this config in boot device order:

   1 - UEFI: USB
   2 - Windows Boot Manger
   3 - Others

   - with CSM (Compatibility Support Module): enable -> GRUB appears and selecting try Ubuntu then a black windows appears and nothing happens. The same result if install ubuntu is selected.
   - With Secure Boot disable -> and this config in boot device order:

   1 - USB (No UEFI)
   2 - Windows Boot Manger
   3 - Others

   - with CSM (Compatibility Support Module): enable -> GRUB appears and selecting try Ubuntu, -> Ubuntu boots and we can even install it.
5. Rebooting and just changing the boot order as

   1 - Ubuntu []
   2 - Windows Boot Manger
   3 - Others
   then nothings happens.
6. Booting from LiveUSB again and, as per instructed, making Boot-Repair (A warning windows: Ubuntu is working in legacy mode.).
7. Saving changes and rebooting, Grub works but selecting Ubuntu, a black windows appears and nothing happens. Selecting Win8, Win8 boots and works.

Up until now we are unable to install Ubuntu.  Any suggestion will be welcomed.

Kind regards and thanks in advance.

Comment: @Alvar the questioner is saying he/she is following that question and it does not work.

Comment: @WarrenHill then add a comment on that answer...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The link on UEFI boot is pretty good, but most do not discuss the additional issues that Ultrabooks have. You have Intel SRT which (somehow) uses RAID to access the SSD. You have to turn off Intel SRT, and  remove the RAID meta-data from both drives to get Ubuntu to install in UEFI mode.

Some computers just will not install in UEFI mode. They have (not per UEFI standard) modified UEFI to only boot Windows efi file. But there are work arounds for that. Boot-Repair can convert a BIOS install to UEFI and if needed rename files as a work around.

Ultrabooks also have dual video and if in nVidia mode you need nomodeset. Some allow you to set it to Intel video only but many are just automatic. Then you need to install bumblebee to use dual video.

Intel Smart Response Technology

http://www.intel.com/p/en_US/support/highlights/chpsts/imsm

```
sudo dmraid -E -r /dev/sda
sudo dmraid -E -r /dev/sdb
```

When you reimplement Intel SRT it will work again.

Bumblebee:

https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Bumblebee

http://www.webupd8.org/2013/04/set-up-bumblebee-with-bumblebee.html

More info here:

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2147295