# Unable to install bootloader

Tags: installation, 12.10, grub2, ssd

I am trying to install Ubuntu 12.10 on a HP ENVY Ultrabook 6-1113tx with Windows 8 pre-installed, off of a LiveUSB. We tried installing Ubuntu 12.04 onto his 32GB SSD by overwriting Windows 8 with Ubuntu butI receive this error message at the very end.

```
    Failed to install grub-efi to /target/ the system will not boot.
```

After, I ran boot-repair, followed the recommended steps but it did not help ([Here is the output](http://paste.ubuntu.com/5938866/)).

I switched then to trying to install to Ubuntu 12.10, which recognized that 12.04 had been installed and offered the option to upgrade. However, I picked to install over 12.04, but the same error message comes up.

I also tried to format both hard drives (500GB HDD and a 32GB SSD on the laptop) with GParted from the LiveUSB and reinstalled Ubuntu 12.10 from the `Install Ubuntu` option, but the same error again.

My question is: How can I install Ubuntu cleanly and avoid this error? Is it worth attempting to try installing 13.04 or would we just receive a similar error? If I were to manually create and assign the installation partitions (swap, boot, home) to the SSD would that work?

Thanks for any help that anyone can offer.

Answer (score 0):

UEFI is the Option Which Allows to Install Only One Operating system at a time in the Base Machine And its secured one Disable the UEFI and Try to install u can install multiple Operating system ..

Answer (score 0):

If an Ultra-book it uses Intel SRT. That uses RAID on the drives which cause issues for grub to install correctly.

See this thread:

[Ubuntu 12.04.2 Dual boot UEFI Windows 8 Preinstalled CX21903W Ultrabook](https://askubuntu.com/questions/327897/ubuntu-12-04-2-dual-boot-uefi-windows-8-preinstalled-cx21903w-ultrabook/327921#327921)

Shows install with screen shots.

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI

Also shows Windows 8 screens

[Installing Ubuntu Alongside a Pre-Installed Windows with UEFI](https://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-on-a-pre-installed-uefi-supported-windows-8-system)

Comment: Hi there, thanks for the links. I followed the instructions there and in another thread but still can't get the ultrabook to work. [Here](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1W4oO654zpXYS9oqrfDiJRwWHPOmPx7yPt5WhHsOJDAo/edit?usp=sharing) is some brief documentation and the output that we got from the terminal.